# Run background JOB with COGI without changing the screens

Tags: transactions, background, abap, jobs, sap-erp

I'm trying to run a background job on COGI, so that it fills the selection screen and presses ctrl+shift+f12 to alter the batch of a document.

The SHDB transaction was executed with nobinpt parameter on and standard size parameter on. After recording I used those parameters to create the following code:

```
options-nobinpt = abap_true.
options-updmode = 'A'.
options-dismode = 'N'.
options-racommit = abap_true.
options-defsize = abap_true.



CALL TRANSACTION 'COGI' USING it_bdcdata

                          OPTIONS FROM options
                          MESSAGES INTO it_msg.
```

It works on foreground perfectly and even with the "N" - background processing parameter also it works,/
but when I try to run the program as a job it doesn't work, even thought it doesn't show any error messages.

When I tried to run SHDB simulating background it shows a different screen after selection, which doesn't allow any changes to the document.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Is there a way to set the screen to be the same as foreground execution during batch?

Thanks

Comment: `it shows a different screen after selection, which doesn't allow any changes to the document` so try to understand what this screen means and how to omit. Very probably it block the background processing

Comment: @Suncatcher, yes, this screen is the one blocking the background processing.

Comment: Using batch-input instructions for automatization is very error-prone and fragile. I would advise against it. Did you try to find a BAPI which can do what you want or at least a regular function module?

Comment: @Philipp, yes we tried to find a module for it, but there isn't any, COGI is very old and very poorly maintained, but essential in this moment for the company.Since the processing on this transaction is very great and involves many tables we opted for a batch input because it uses the standard program.

Answer (score 0):

CALL TRANSACTION should be used to run dialog transactions only. COGI is a report transaction i.e. it calls selection screen 1000 of the report CORUAFFW:
[COGI definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efigE.png)

Therefore you should use the [SUBMIT](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapsubmit.htm) statement to call the report CORUAFFW, not CALL TRANSACTION.